# How to pass a color from one Composable to another?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I pass a color from one Composable to another? The problem is that the color value in question "cannot be reassigned", so it seems I can't pass it as a parameter.

So, basically, this is a snippet from the first Composable:

```
val buttonColor = when (index) {
                0 -> if (isEnabled) Color(0xff81C784)
                else disabledColor
                1 -> if (isEnabled) Color(0xff9575CD)
                else disabledColor
                2 -> if (isEnabled) Color(0xffFF8A65)
                else disabledColor
                3 -> if (isEnabled) Color(0xff5C6BC0)
                else disabledColor
                else -> Color.Unspecified
            }

            Button(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).height(60.dp),
                elevation = ButtonConstants.defaultElevation(8.dp),
                colors = ButtonConstants.defaultButtonColors(
                    backgroundColor = buttonColor
                ),
```

And I want to use that buttonColor as an accent color in the second Composable:

```
CustomToggle(color = color,
                    selected = isDisabled.value,
                    onSelected = {
                        isDisabled.value = !isDisabled.value
                        when (index) {

                        }
                    }
                )
```

My idea was simply to bring in the color as a parameter in my parent composable:

```
@Composable
    fun MainInterface(context: Context, color: Color) {
    
    [...]


            bodyContent = {
                ScrollableColumn(horizontalAlignment = CenterHorizontally) {
                    QuickOptions(context, color)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))
                    SoundOptions(color)
                }
}
```

But I can't as I can't pass buttonColor as a parameter... I tried to insert the second Composable inside the first one but I still can't pass the color to the second Composable.

Comment: It feels like your color is some `State` (e.g., `remember { mutableStateOf<Color>() }` that the first composable should modify and the second composable should reference. Then, when the first composable modifies the state, the second composable will be recomposed and use the new color.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's right and I need to implement something called state hoisting. I am not sure how to do it in the above case, so any help would be welcome.

Comment: If you view your composables as a call tree, somewhere, there is a call that is common between those two composables. That could be the `setContent()` lambda at the root or perhaps a bit farther down the tree. Wherever that is, declare your `State` and pass it down the call trees to those two composables, so one can read from it and the other can modify it. Here, you have "hoisted" that `State` to the nearest common composable.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Still struggling to apply it but I'll get there eventually!

Comment: Ok, I've got it thanks to this very helpful article: https://codingtroops.com/android/jetpack-compose-part-3-how-to-add-state/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I would explain what I did, in the hope that it might help someone else in future.

First, in my top composable, the Scaffold, I added the mutable state variable. Then the two Composables. The top one changes the value of accentColor, the second one receives the new value:

```
Scaffold(
            ...
            
            bodyContent = {

                val accentColor = remember { mutableStateOf(Color(0xff81C784)) }

                QuickOptions(accentColor.value) { newColor ->
                        accentColor.value = newColor}
                    
                SoundOptions(accentColor = accentColor)

                }
            },
        )
```

Then I indicated what colors had to be passed in the onClick event of the first Composable:

```
@Composable
fun QuickOptions(accentColor: Color, onColorChanged: (Color) -> Unit) {

...

onClick = {
                    if (isSelectable == true) {
                        val newColor = when (index) {
                            0 -> Color(0xff81C784)
                            1 -> Color(0xff9575CD)
                            2 -> Color(0xffFF8A65)
                            3 -> Color(0xff9FA8DA)
                            else -> Color.Unspecified
                        }
                        onColorChanged(newColor)
                        
... }
```

Finally I passed this to the second Composable:

```
@Composable
fun SoundOptions(accentColor: MutableState<Color>) {
...

CustomToggle(
                    color = accentColor.value
                ) {}
    }
```

Good luck!